# This sql not compiling but not sure why

Tags: sql

I am getting error here: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'FACILITY_NPI'.

not sure why the 'f' is plainly there.

```
SELECT f.FACILITY_ID, count(f.FACILITY_ID) C
FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A  
Inner join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI
INNER JOIN PBM.USER_FACILITY uf  ON f.FACILITY_ID = uf.FACILITY_ID
```

Comment: is there a `FACILITY_NPI` column in `PBM.FACILITY`?

Comment: does that column exist though ? Does it have a differnt name in both tables (the underscore) ?

Comment: also you're selecting an individual column and doing a `count()` in the same query without a `GROUP BY` - that will not compile either.

Comment: No there is not FACILITY_NPI in that table. so this must be 'dead code' in the app codes. but this is the full code in the app i was trying to debug pieces:

Comment: var dtFacilityCount = Utils.GetDataTable(@"SELECT f.FACILITY_ID, count(f.FACILITY_ID) C
                        FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A  
                        Inner join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI
                        INNER JOIN PBM.USER_FACILITY uf  ON f.FACILITY_ID = uf.FACILITY_ID   
                        Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  AND  
                        uf.USER_ID=" + userID + @"
                        Group by f.FACILITY_ID");

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would expect to be able to join on a column that does not exist in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However it shouldn't compile because you are doing a count and a select on a column that is not in a GROUP BY or a MAX/MIN function (aggregate function)

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget the `AS` for the aliases ?

`SELECT column AS C FROM somewhere AS W`

Comment: `AS` is optional in most (if not all) systems.